# 3D CharacterController ride moving platforms in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I have a **player controller script** that I'm writing that **uses the `CharacterController` component** to move around and handle collisions. I've been able to implement basically every feature that I want **except for moving platforms**.

**Some things to note:**

-For testing purposes, the **platform moves via the `Update()` function and does not have a `Rigidbody` component** attached to it. I don't think that rigidbodies would make a difference in the first place, but I could be wrong.

-Currently, when my player stands on the platform, it *kind of* does what it's supposed to do, but **it moves with a large amount of jitter.** In other words, the player isn't able to depenetrate itself as fast as the platform moves, therefore causing the jitter.

**Here's what I've tried:**

My initial thought was to create a **script on the moving platform that keeps track of its own velocity.** Then, on the player's `OnControllerColliderHit(...)` function, I would get the platform's velocity and add it to the player's velocity. **This caused the same jittery effect as before.**

My next idea was to **parent the player to the platform** whenever the player collided with it. This solution also did not work because **apparently `CharacterController`s do NOT like it when they are a child of a moving object.** The platform's transformations had little to no effect on the player, regardless of its speed. So once again, **the jitteriness continued.**

Just to test out possible solutions, I also tried combining the two previous fixes and still, the jitteriness lives among us.

**Closing thoughts:**

I'm beginning to think that it's not entirely possible, but I'm still holding out hope. I would also prefer to not to purchase an existing asset or switch to a `Rigidbody` component because neither would fit the style of my game.

Feel free to ask questions for more details and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the built-in CharacterController, but I can tell you how I have implemented this for my own character controller (although, I should warn you it is almost definitely more convoluted than necessary).

I made this class

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CopyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] public GameObject target;
    Transform target_transform;
    Transform common_ancestor;

    Quaternion previousAncestorRotation;
    Vector3 previousAncestorPosition;

    Matrix4x4 previousTargetWorldToLocal;
    Quaternion previousTargetRotation;

    void Start(){
        if(target!=null)
            Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize(){
        target_transform = target.transform;
        common_ancestor = Utils.FindCommonAncestor(transform, target_transform);
        if(common_ancestor!=null){
            previousAncestorPosition= common_ancestor.position;
            previousAncestorRotation = common_ancestor.rotation;
        }

        previousTargetWorldToLocal = target_transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
        previousTargetRotation = target_transform.rotation;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //if the objects do not share ancestors, it's fairly straightforward: calculate the position and rotation of the constrained object in the local space of the previous parent pose, and 
        //move it to the same pose in the _current_ local space

        //if they are part of the same hierarchy, however, the transformations of the common ancestors get applied twice to the constrained object (once naturally, once because of this script)
        //so, we just apply the inverse of the movement of the common ancestors to correct it. Simple, right?
        if(target!=null){

            Vector3 pointInPreviousLocalSpace = previousTargetWorldToLocal.MultiplyPoint(transform.position);
            Quaternion rotationInPreviousLocalSpace =  Quaternion.Inverse(previousTargetRotation) * transform.rotation;

            //set up the whole common-ancestor thing
            Quaternion offsetAncestorRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Matrix4x4 ancestorMatrix = Matrix4x4.identity;
            if(common_ancestor!=null){
                offsetAncestorRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(previousAncestorRotation) * common_ancestor.rotation;
                ancestorMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(
                    common_ancestor.worldToLocalMatrix.MultiplyVector(previousAncestorPosition-common_ancestor.position), 
                    Quaternion.Inverse(offsetAncestorRotation),
                    Vector3.one
                );
            }

            //the thing happens!
            Matrix4x4 theMatrix;
            if(common_ancestor!=null)
                theMatrix = common_ancestor.localToWorldMatrix* ancestorMatrix * common_ancestor.worldToLocalMatrix * target_transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            else
                theMatrix = target_transform.localToWorldMatrix;
                
            transform.SetPositionAndRotation( theMatrix.MultiplyPoint(pointInPreviousLocalSpace),  
                Quaternion.Inverse(offsetAncestorRotation) * target_transform.rotation * rotationInPreviousLocalSpace);
            

            //store the current local space information for next time
            previousTargetWorldToLocal = target_transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
            previousTargetRotation = target_transform.rotation;

            if(common_ancestor!=null){
                previousAncestorRotation = common_ancestor.rotation;
                previousAncestorPosition = common_ancestor.position;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And added a component of this type to the character. Then, inside of the character controller, when checking the ground that it is standing on, I change the settings of the CopyMovement. The abridged version of that code is something like this:

```
CopyMovement groundParentConstraint;

bool checkGround(){
    if(castRayDownwards()){
        if(groundParentConstraint.target != hit.collider.gameObject){
            groundParentConstraint.target = hit.collider.gameObject;
            groundParentConstraint.Initialize();
        }
        return true;
    }
    else{
        groundParentConstraint.target = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

On top of this being a bit convoluted, it also does not work when the "parent" (the platform, in this case) has root motion animation, but do not ask me why, because I have no clue. But still, it's better than nothing.

Edit:
The "find common ancestor" function:

```
public static Transform FindCommonAncestor(Transform tr1, Transform tr2){
    HashSet<Transform> ancestors1 = new HashSet<Transform>();
    Transform p = tr1;
    while(p!=null){
        ancestors1.Add(p);
        p=p.parent;
    }
    p=tr2;

    while(p!=null){
        if(ancestors1.Contains(p))
            return p;
        p=p.parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. I don't work with matrices all that often so it's a little bit hard for me to read. Also, what are ancestors in this case? And how are you finding them in your `Utils.FindCommonAncestor` function?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, that function is a custom thing. I added the code for it to the answer. What I mean by "common ancestor" is just a GameObject (or, Transform, I guess) that is in the hierarchy of both the constrained object (the player) and the target (the platform). So, for example, a shared parent. For this specific use case a common ancestor probably does not even exist, but the code was meant to be more generic and work in more cases.